# singularity of hypersurface section

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose $X$ is a very general sextic surface in $\mathbb{P}^3$ and $Z$ be  a locally complete intersection zero dimensional subscheme of length at least $23$. What can we say about the dimension of quintic hypersurface section which are singular along $Z$ ? Can we say something about its upper bound ?

Comment: Is $Z \subset X$?

Comment: Yes. It is inside $X$.

Comment: You may consider giving context and motivation for your question. Why are you interested? Why 23?

Comment: It is known that m general double points with few exceptions impose independent contions. So for the case of quintic if m \ge 14 then there is no such quintic. On the other hand, I saw a result that says that a quintic hyper surface can have at most 31 nodes. Therefore the question is what will happen if the points are not general and m lies between 15 to 31. of course if all m points are colinear then it is easy. In general if not all colinear and also not general then how many such quintics possible. 23 is just a no between 25 to 31.

Comment: Since it a quantic hypaersurface section in a very general sextic surface, a line can not contain more than 6 points.